# Reverse Counting of String From Specified Position

Tags: c#, winforms

This seems to be a novice question but I've tried a reverse one. Now little bit confused to try another one. I've a requirement and already tried the following with `ListBox`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listBox1.Items.Add("123456 - Hello World 1!");
    listBox1.Items.Add("7891011 - Hello World 2!");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
   {
       int i = item.ToString().IndexOf('-') + 1;
       string msg = item.ToString().Substring(i);

       MessageBox.Show(msg);
   }
}
```

On button click, it returns the following result I mean the words after the **(-)** sign:

```
Hello World 2!
```

Now I would like to try the other one that should return the following:

```
7891011
```

I can do it this way -

```
item.ToString().IndexOf('-') - 6;
```

But would prefer a better way to do it and any idea would be appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `.Split('-')` and then decide if `[0]` for the first part or `[1]` for the second?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Split()` method of string class? [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b873y76a(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: It would be wonderful if I could mark all posts as an answer but thanks all for the ideas and still long way to go to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
string data = item.ToString();
string msg = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf('-') - 1);
```

Alternatively, if you need both, and if spaces around `-` are  mandatory, then you can use `-` as a split separator (mind the spaces):

```
string[] parts = item.ToString().Split(new[] {" - "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
string msg1 = parts[0];
string msg2 = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a method of string called [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) that will split on a character(s) or string and return a `string[]` of all the different parts.

In your example:

```
string input = "7891011 - Hello World 2!";
string[] splitArray = input.Split('-');

//splitArray[0] = "7891011 "
//splitArray[1] = " Hello World 2!"
```

You can decide which "part" of the string you want from there.  You can [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) the whitespace off of each part too so you have a more "pure" string.

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bUDiCU) to demonstrate.

Comment: You beat me to typing it out.  This is definitely the best bet, since you know the input well.

Comment: Wow 3 people wrote the same answer AND other people got beaten to it as well including me. Guess this was a pretty easy one.

Answer (score 1):

try split

```
    private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        foreach (string item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            string[] values = item.ToString().Split('-');                

            MessageBox.Show( values[0] );
            MessageBox.Show( values[1] );
        }
    }
```

split, cut the string when found a separator character, then generate array of strings, now you can use all separates strings

Answer (score 1):

This type of question is a perfect fit for [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx).

Once a string is split based on the character.. the string is then made into an array.  Then, just call the index of the wanted string.

Here is the code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lstOfStrings = new List<string>();
        string stringOne = "123456 - Hello World 1!";
        string stringTwo = "7891011 - Hello World 2!";

        lstOfStrings.Add(stringOne);
        lstOfStrings.Add(stringTwo);

        foreach(var item in lstOfStrings)
        {
            var stringSplit = item.Split('-'); 
            /* split the item (in this case) in half where the character = '-'.. and store
             the result in an array object called stringSplit */

            var firstHalf = stringSplit[0].Trim();
            /* I want to get the 1st element of the
             array (0 based indexing) and then remove all of the white space */

            var secondHalf = stringSplit[1].Trim(); 
            /* I want to get the 2nd element of
            the array (0 based indexing) and then remove all of the white space */

            Console.WriteLine(firstHalf);
            Console.WriteLine(secondHalf);
        }

    }

}

// Output:

// 123456
// Hello World 1!
// 7891011
// Hello World 2!
```

Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Zos0S)

Use `.Trim()` to remove whitespace from strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind objects to ListBox instead of strings. This is more elegant approach and solves your problem as well.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(new { Id = "123456", Text = "123456 - Hello World 1!" });
    listBox1.Items.Add(new { Id = "7891011", Text = "123456 - Hello World 2!" });
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (dynamic item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great @Faruq - Thanks.